# Delphi: How to repaint windows while minimized?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, taskbar

I have a Delphi2010 application with a single form that displays some dynamic content. When it's minimized to the Windows taskbar, the taskbar "preview" is static and doesn't update. Is there a fix/workaround?

To replicate, stick a label and a timer on the main form and make the `OnTimer` event set the `TLabel`'s caption to the current time.

The taskbar preview is dynamic, until the form is minimized.

Comment: What is the value of MainFormOnTaskbar?

Comment: True. But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: This is a winapi question, not related to delphi. The problem is not not being able to paint the window but to update the thumbnail preview. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#thumbnails).